# eslint rule to require React components to extend React.Component?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Is there an eslint plugin to detect warnings of the form

`Warning: App(...): React component classes must extend React.Component.`

and, ideally, fix them automatically?

Edit: Perhaps a close approximation is finding classes that don't extend React.Component but have a render() method that returns JSX.

(Relevant for upgrading from React 0.13 to 0.14, since [extending React.Component is now required](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an eslint plugin to solve this problem, which can also fix the pertinent class definitions:

https://github.com/yoz/react-extends-component

It does a first approximation, finding ES6 classes that have a `render()` method and no superclasses (since I would rather not warn for components that extend other components, and these eventually have to extend React.Component anyway).